# Interpolation based on $n$ uniformly distributed points

Tags: inequality, numerical-methods, interpolation

We are given $n+1$ uniformly distributed points in the segment $[0,1]$: $x_i=\frac{i}{n}$, $i=0,1,...,n$ and a function $f(x)=e^{-x}$

$P(x)$ is the interpolation polynomial of $f(x)$ where $P(x_i)=f(x_i)$ for all $i$.

We define $h=\frac{1}{n}$.

Show that for any $x\in [0,1]$ we get $|(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\dots(x-x_n)|\leq \frac{n!h^{n+1}}{4}$

I'm not entirely sure where to begin. Perhaps induction is a good way to start? I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your points are $0, h, 2h, ..., (n - 1) h, 1$, this means that the largest value of your expression happens when $x =0$. Reformulate as a statement when the points are $0, 1, 2, \ldots, n$, that will be easier to handle.

Comment: But at $x=0$ won't $x-x_0 = 0 - 0 = 0$ give the expression its *minimum* value?